# webview shouldOverrideUrlLoading not working

Tags: android, webview

I call my file in my local storage in html format and display in webview. in my html contain a url which will click and display in the same webview. But when i call shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not working. Any help?

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///"+file); 
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());


private class InsideWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);

    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return true;` instead

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: tried. still no response when click the link. But when i use loaddata rather than loadurl it can work.

Comment: is the content of your file shown and the click is not handled, or the file is not shown at all

Answer (score 1):

Loading url with scheme like `file:///android_asset`, and `iframes` will not
trigger `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.